# How to "Reset" argparse.ArgumentParser() for multiple calls

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I have a script that will be called 1 or more times from a pyqt4 GUI. It runs just fine the 1st time but the 2nd time the script is called I get the following error:

[17848] Failed to execute script script_name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script_name.py", line 61, in 
TypeError: invalid file: None

I pass in and assign the arguments like so:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', help= 'input directory location')
parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', help= 'output directory location')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--logfile', help= 'error log file')

args = parser.parse_args()

directory = args.input
outputDir = args.output
logFile = open(args.logfile, 'w')
```

I believe what is happening is that the ArgumentParser() needs to be reset. I did find exit() and I call parser.exit() at the end of the script but this didn't work. I am not actually sure if this is the problem though. Any ideas?

Note: I don't believe this is a file open issue - I removed all of the code that had to do with the logfile and it then threw the error on the "directory" argument.

Any help will be appreciated - thank you

Comment: Is the code you are executing above in a separate script from pyqt, or an imported module?

Comment: A `parser` does not have a state.  Each time `parse_args` is called, it parses the input `sys.argv` list a new.  I'm not sure how you are calling the script the 2nd time, but I suspect it is missing the `input`, `output` arguments that you used the first time.

Comment: @Stephen Rauch - TY for responding. Yes this is a separate script that I have packaged up w/ pyinstaller. The user will process xml files and then want to keep the GUI open to process the next batch of files and that is when the error is thrown...

Comment: @hpaulj TY for responding. I will look in to that possibility...

Comment: But if it is a separate script, it should start over fresh each time.  So if you have a problem the second time, it is almost certainly with the caller, as @hpaulj mentioned.

Comment: @Stephen Rauch - That definitely sounds reasonable  - gonna check that out this evening or tomorrow...

Comment: @hpaulj you were correct :). So now I need to see where I want to go with this. Thank you again.